# Using environment variables in Firefox browser URL

Tags: firefox, url, variables, environment

I was trying to browse some html files in my unix path using Firefox browser.Is there any way to use environment variables as URL in Firefox? And possibly bookmark it?

For instance:

```
file://$PATH/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely not possible since environmental variables in unix are associated with your shell. Ex. defined in .bashrc. As far as I know, Firefox has no interaction with your shell, though that's not to say it couldn't be programmed to via an extension.